# How to Duplicate Dropbox/Ubuntu One Folder Synchronization In-House?

Tags: windows, linux, sync, dropbox, unison

I really like using Dropbox and Ubuntu One, but they don't quite cut it for my workplace, because of restrictions on using external services.

Is there software (preferably free/open source) that we can run on our Linux server in-house, that will provide the functionality offered by these various pieces of folder syncing software?

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best thing you can probably do is to just create a folder and then looking more into [rsync](http://www.samba.org/rsync/) (one way) and [unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) (a lot more like Mesh and Drop Box) which should be able to synchronise two directories for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this git wrapper: [Git-Sync folder synchronization for Linux](http://code.google.com/p/git-sync)
It works really nicely here.

Comment: What would you recommend for mounting network locations? I suppose, git-sync requires two folders?

Comment: sshfs and curlftpfs will let you mount ssh and ftp, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

[Crashplan](http://www.crashplan.com/) is free if you're only backing up to your own drives/machines, otherwise they charge for online storage.

Answer (score 0):

Old question is old, but [Duplicati](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplicati_%28software%29) is exactly what you are looking for.
I found this thread googling for other such alternatives, so I thought I'd mention it for the sake of relevance and archival purposes. :)

Answer (score 0):

[SparkeShare](https://github.com/hbons/SparkleShare) is an GIT-backed open source Dropbox clone available for Linux, Mac and Windows.